# How to assign different values to NA within Rcmdr?

Tags: r

missing data are represented as 9999.00 , 9999.0 and 9999.000 in a text file.
if I specify in the:

```
    Rcmdr->data->import->missing data indicator  as  9999,nothing will be assigned to NA.

   but when I assigned to 9999.0  then only the values of 9999.0 are assigned to NA.
```

is there any-idea on how to assign different values to NA within Rcmdr.
Here is the code added:

```
      Dataset <- 
    read.table("C:/Users/BRSa12002_L4_d.txt", 
     header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="-9999.00", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
```

Comment: I do not use Rcmdr (it's quite simple to do this with R). However a quick workaround would be to use a text editor to replace these values with NA.

Comment: I would just read in raw data and set those values to NA by hand. Something along the lines of `my.obj[my.obj == 999.0] <- NA; my.obj[my.obj == 999.00] <- NA`. Assuming the values are read in as factors. It would be nice if we would see a head of the file you're trying to import, or better yet, `str` of the imported file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?read.table` we learn that argument na.strings takes a vector. Thus, you can use this to assign several different values as NA.

```
Dataset <- read.table("C:/Users/BRSa12002_L4_d.txt", 
               header=TRUE, sep=",", 
               na.strings=c("-9999.00","-9999.0","-9999"), 
               dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rcmdr is just a menu-GUI, so it probably uses standard input functions. The `read.table` function works on values as strings. You give the `read.table`function a parameter named `na.strings`. I seriously doubt that it evaluates the input to see if it is numerically the same.  The default string is "NA". I'm not a Rcmdr user, but my prediction is that you could give that function both "9999" and "9999.0" and get the behavior you desired. The real question is what is in your input data stream. You have not yet explained that question.

The best way to get an answer would be to copy the R code that appears when you execute that menu-driven command. We can then add the appropriate strings to the R code to get you where you want to go. It's possible that Rcmdr cannot achieve a complete answer. It's really designed as a starter method to get you up to speed with understanding command-line R. (Most of us took the other route and started using R from the command line in the very beginning, so you may need to help us out a bit.)